# How to push from seconds tables results(ARRAY) into first tables results (ARRAY)

Tags: php, mysql, json

> rent_property (table name)

```
id     fullName    propertyName

1       A          House Name1

2       B          House Name2

3       C          House Name3

4       D          House Name4
```

> rent_amenity (table name)

```
rentamenityId         rentPropertyId       amenityName

1                         1                 Lift
2                         1                 Gym

3                         2                 Power backup
4                         4                 Gym
```

> my sql query

```
    $sql = "SELECT a.id,a.fullName,a.propertyName FROM rent_property a LEFT JOIN rent_amenity b ON  a.id = b.rentPropertyId WHERE a.city='1' AND a.propertyType IN ( '1','2' ) AND b.amenityName IN ( 'Gym' )  AND a.approveStatus!='Inactive' GROUP BY a.id order by a.id desc";

$result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
```

> my dynamic function

```
public function GetJoinRecord($query_string){

        $con = $this->DBConnection();
        $query = mysqli_query($con,$query_string);
        if(@mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

                while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $record[] = $data;
                }
                mysqli_free_result($query);

            }

            mysqli_close($con); 
            return $record;
    }
```

**based on my table and mysql query i should get two records ,and also i am getting correctly, but i am not able to make my expected results,please see below i will posted currently what i am getting the results and what is my expected results**

> Current Out Put

```
 {
"status": "success",
"message": "Data Found.",
"data": {
    "rent_id": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "fullName": "D",
            "propertyName": "House Name4"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "fullName": "A",
            "propertyName": "House Name1"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

> My Expected Results

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "Data Found.",
"data": {
    "rent_id": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "fullName": "D",
            "propertyName": "House Name4",
             "amenities":[
                    {
                       "rentamenityId":"4",
                       "rentPropertyId":"4",
                       "amenityName":"Gym"
                    }
                 ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "fullName": "A",
            "propertyName": "House Name1",
            "amenities":[
                    {
                       "rentamenityId":"1",
                       "rentPropertyId":"1",
                       "amenityName":"Lift"
                    },
                    {
                       "rentamenityId":"2",
                       "rentPropertyId":"1",
                       "amenityName":"Gym"
                    }
                 ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Here i want to add amenities array(**amenity name**) from my second table(**rent_amenity**) based on my property, I don't how to push the amenities records in my first array.

Comment: Your select columns only specify `a.id,a.fullName,a.propertyName` so you only get those columns back. Also your where specifies that you only want properties with a gym `b.amenityName IN ( 'Gym' )` so you will only get one row for each property that has a gym.

Comment: @Matt Rink,How i can write the sql query,can you update your answer,

Answer (score 0):

You would want something closer to the following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rent_property a 
LEFT JOIN rent_amenity b ON a.id = b.rentPropertyId 
WHERE a.city='1' AND a.propertyType IN ( '1','2' ) 
/* AND b.amenityName IN ( 'Gym' ) -- Removed to return all properties */
AND a.approveStatus!='Inactive' 
GROUP BY a.id order by a.id desc
```

However this will return one row for each amenity in your property so you will have to process each property and retrieve handle it's amenities as you loop over the rows.

The other alternative would be to use a single query to retrieve the properties and then a second query to retrieve the amenities for the properties returned.

Comment: Can you make please my expected results, i am not able to do,i need exact my expected results with my json